# Is there a way to make my credential information not return after I insert it into my database

Tags: mysql

Lets say if I wanted to insert an user infomation into `Users` table in my database, the following is a json format of the information I want to insert:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'username': 'asd123',
    'password': 'abc123'
}
```

How can I make it return only the `id` and the `username` when I do a `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
SELECT *
```

use

```
SELECT id, username
```

Explanation: `*` is used when we want all columns, otherwise use the specific column names. Use `*` only when it is required.

Comment: I know it is probably dumb to ask. But is there a way to not return my `password` if I insist on using `SELECT *`?

Comment: No, `*` means all column. And its not recommended to use `*` when you needs only one or two columns as it require more resources to hold the entire row in result set.

Comment: Is there a way to make something like this? A nested column?     `{
    user: {
        ‘id’: 1,
        ‘username’: ‘abc123’
    },
    ‘password’: ‘abc123’
}`

Comment: Make an array of the format you desired and `json_encode()` it.